# create a shared folder for sftp with support to nginx

Tags: nginx, sftp

I have a nginx server for some customers, and in this server some websites.

One customer asked to me a ftp access to sendo some files, I installed a sftp in my ubuntu server, already created the user, added password and made permission 775 to his folder, inside of this folder, another folder called ftp with permissions for his user

The website of this customer use subdomain, and I think this the reason for not work, I have some other custumers without subdomain and everything work fine.

Some hints please?

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    root /srv/www/example.com.br;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name caraiga.com.br www.example.com.br;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location /volks {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /volks/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location /audi {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /audi/index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(php|phtml)?$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(git|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|ico)?$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
        expires -1;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ ^/ftp(.*) {
        alias /home/example/ftp/;
        try_files $1 $1/ index.html /index.php =404;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        location ~ .*\.(php|phtml)?$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/example$request_uri;
            fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no one? ;-; please I need some help

Comment: Your question seems to me extremely hard to understand. What isn't working? FTP access? nginx access? Customer wants to upload files via FTP and make them downloadable via HTTP for others? Or to update a site via FTP? What do you mean by installing SFTP server? SFTP is a SSH extension and has (almost) nothing to do with FTP/FTPS.

Comment: I made the access to sftp works, now my customer can access the LP folder. But now I can't access any other file than index.html, I need to access a JPG image, but I'm getting a 404 error

the full address is something like http://www.example.com/lp/image.jpg

what I have to change in my config file?

thanks!